# Javascript, trying to write part of a function to body

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>

function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            // I can do alert(marker.postion); here... but, I want that value I want in the body
</head>
```

How can I `document.write()` the `var marker.position` in the body.  I can alert it in the head, but can't write it to the body.  I need that value to input the LatLng into the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can  need to assign the variable to the value of an input field or the innerhtml of a tag (like span,div,...)

example javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('marker1').value = marker.position;
document.getElementById('marker2').innerHTML =  marker.position;
```

example html:

```
<input type="text" id="marker1" value=""/>
<div id="marker2"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't use `.innerHTML`, you want to use `.textContent`